# How to get 2 sidebars onto one page?

Tags: html, css, sidebar

For my website, I want to use 2 navigation bars; a horizontal one at the very top, and the other one under the first, a vertical one this time, and on the left of my text content so that the text wraps around it. How would I achieve this?

When I copy and paste CSS codes from websites such as w3schools.com, both codes will stuff up. Right now, it's either one navigation bar or two very strange-looking ones.

The second sidebar should look similar to the hyperlinked one on Wikipedia.

Here's the code. Sorry if it's too long.

```css
ul {
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
border: none;
font-size: 20;
font-family: "candara",cambria, sans-serif;
list-style-type: none;
margin-top: -10px;
margin-left: -8px;
margin-right: -8px;
padding: 1px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

li {
text-align: centre;
border-bottom: none;
}

li:last-child {
border-bottom: none;
}

li {
float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
display: inline-block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}    

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
color: black;
background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

li.dropdown {
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

.active {
background-color: #4682B4;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
}

div.one {
background-color:white;
border-style: solid;
border-color:#F5F5F5;
border-width: 1px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px
}
```

```html
<html>
<head><title>Introduction to Goldfish</title>
<link rel="icon" href="Images/Goldfish.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Goldfish.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropbtn">Enter</a>
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div>
<hr style="height:40pt; visibility:hidden;"/>
<div class="one">
<hr style="height:5pt; visibility:hidden;"/>
<center><img src="Assignment/Aquarium.jpg"</center>
<hr style="height:20pt; visibility:hidden;"/>
<h1 style="text-align:left;"><div style="font-family:candara;">Your First         Goldfish</div></h1>
<div style="font-family:candara;"><p style="text-align:left;"><font     size="4">Congratulations on your first goldfish! Oh dear, I sound like a     grandmother congratulating her daughter on her first child, don't I? Anyway,     keeping goldfish as pets is a rewarding, calming and educational experience of     people of all ages.
<br>
<br>
Millions of fish are bought each year and it's easy to see why.
<br>
<br>
Goldfish are delightful creatures to watch, bumping against each other to chase after another morsel of food, following you as you walk around, and zooming around the tank.
Additionally, there are so many varieties to choose from, all in different shapes, sizes and colours.
<br>
<br>
Hopefully that got your attention. Now, let me tell you more about these delightful goldies you've bought. Let's just say that it requires more work than just dropping a few flakes into their small glass bowl and changing their tank water once every few months.
</font></p></style>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need add `<ul> <li> </ li> </ ul>` in your dropdown:

In your html :

```
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>

 </div>
```

Execute in code snippet:

```css
ul {
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
border: none;
font-size: 20;
font-family: "candara",cambria, sans-serif;
list-style-type: none;
margin-top: -10px;
margin-left: -8px;
margin-right: -8px;
padding: 1px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

li {
text-align: centre;
border-bottom: none;
}

li:last-child {
border-bottom: none;
}

li {
float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
display: inline-block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}    

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
color: black;
background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

li.dropdown {
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

.active {
background-color: #4682B4;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
}

div.one {
background-color:white;
border-style: solid;
border-color:#F5F5F5;
border-width: 1px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
 <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Enter</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </div>
    
<li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
     <li> <a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  
    </div>
  </li>
<div>

<hr style="height:40pt; visibility:hidden;"/>
<div class="one">
<hr style="height:5pt; visibility:hidden;"/>
<center><img src="Assignment/Aquarium.jpg"></center>
<hr style="height:20pt; visibility:hidden;"/>
<h1 style="text-align:left;"><div style="font-family:candara;">Your First         Goldfish</div></h1>
<div style="font-family:candara;"><p style="text-align:left;"><font     size="4">Congratulations on your first goldfish! Oh dear, I sound like a     grandmother congratulating her daughter on her first child, don't I? Anyway,     keeping goldfish as pets is a rewarding, calming and educational experience of     people of all ages.
<br>
<br>
Millions of fish are bought each year and it's easy to see why.
<br>
<br>
Goldfish are delightful creatures to watch, bumping against each other to chase after another morsel of food, following you as you walk around, and zooming around the tank.
Additionally, there are so many varieties to choose from, all in different shapes, sizes and colours.
<br>
<br>
Hopefully that got your attention. Now, let me tell you more about these delightful goldies you've bought. Let's just say that it requires more work than just dropping a few flakes into their small glass bowl and changing their tank water once every few months.
</font></p>
</div>
```

hopefully this as you wish